# Project specific variables in IntelliJ configuration

Tags: intellij-idea, configuration

I've been trying to figure out if it is possible to define project specific variables and use them in configurations in IntelliJ IDEA (14):

[image]

I've tried to define those variables in Path Variables section and seems IDEA doesn't replace them with actual values. Is it not supported or am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, this field does not support any wildcards. It's just text field.